# Fundamental Physical Constants in SI Units with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I would like to write e.g. the Bohr magneton in SI units without writing yJ/T and the nuclear magneton (the following code is inconsistent with [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)-notation: `$\mu_\text{N}\approx \SI{5\times 10^{-27}}{\joule\per\tesla}$`), for which exists no SI prefix.

The following MWE provides correct working example (for Bohr magneton):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  Bohr magneton ($\mu_\text{B}\approx \SI{9.27400968}{\yocto\joule\per\tesla}$) and
  nuclear magneton ($\mu_\text{B}\approx {5.05078353\times 10^{-27}}~JT^{-1}$)
\end{document}
```

How can I write the nuclear magneton in the such a SI-form?

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: I think karlkoeller understood my question correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `siunitx` sintax you need to write `5.05078353e-27` to obtain `5.05078353\times 10^{-27}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  Bohr magneton ($\mu_\text{B}\approx \SI{9.27400968}{\yocto\joule\per\tesla}$) and
  nuclear magneton ($\mu_\text{B}\approx \SI{5.05078353e-27}{\joule\per\tesla}$)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, you could of course turn the number parser off